# How to get all cards list for customer on stripe.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Offering for select the payment card (existing) added by customer himself. Using Stripe.Net 1.1.17.0. Since cannot upgrade the version due to client limitation. Is there any way to fetch the card list for provided customer Id ?

Comment: This seems like a question best directed to the developer and owner of Stripe .NET, who I believe is a chap named Jayme Davies.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the list of cards 
`var cardService = new StripeCardService();
IEnumerable<StripeCard> response = cardService.List(*StripeCustomerID*);`